# Ignore Max Value in Mean Calculation in R

Tags: r, filter, max, multiple-columns, mean

I have the following sample df from 20m sprint testing athletes with split times. They do 3 trials. I want to create  new columns for each split that average their two fastest trials (drop the slowest trial).

Here is a sample of the df:

```
    Athlete 0_10m_1 10_20m_1 0_20m_1 0_10m_2 10_20m_2 0_20m_2 0_10m_3 10_20m_3 0_20m_3
1 Athlete 1   2.005    1.320   3.325   1.904    1.306   3.210   1.993    1.316   3.309
2 Athlete 2   1.967    1.383   3.350   1.931    1.391   3.322   2.005    1.399   3.404
3 Athlete 3   2.008    1.381   3.389   2.074    1.365   3.439   2.047    1.408   3.455
4 Athlete 4   1.817    1.286   3.103   1.924    1.285   3.209      NA       NA      NA
```

The end result would be 3 new columns with the mean values of the 2 fastest trials (based on the 0_20m time) ("Avg_0_10m", "Avg_10_20m", Avg_0_20m"). Ideally the solution is robust enough to handle NA values as there will be some within the dataset.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? I'm not sure how to be able to filter out the slowest 0_20m trial with the related split times and average the other trials.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a bit lost to be honest on where to even start. I'm not very strong with R yet. For example, I know how to locate the max value using apply:
apply(df[,c("0_20m_1", "0_20m_2", "0_20m_3")], 1, max). That returns the max values that I want to filter out but how do I "connect" those to the 0_10m and 10_20m of the same trial? I think I need to make it so it's a TRUE/FALSE and not returning a value first. Then I could use an if statement possibly? i.e. if TRUE, don't include in mean function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- read.table(text=" Athlete 0_10m_1 10_20m_1 0_20m_1 0_10m_2 10_20m_2 0_20m_2 0_10m_3 10_20m_3 0_20m_3
'Athlete 1'   2.005    1.320   3.325   1.904    1.306   3.210   1.993    1.316   3.309
'Athlete 2'   1.967    1.383   3.350   1.931    1.391   3.322   2.005    1.399   3.404
'Athlete 3'   2.008    1.381   3.389   2.074    1.365   3.439   2.047    1.408   3.455
'Athlete 4'  1.817    1.286   3.103   1.924    1.285   3.209      NA       NA      NA", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)


x %>%
  gather(trial,time,-Athlete) %>%
  separate(trial, sep = "(?<=m)_", into = c("trial_time", "trial_try")) %>%
  group_by(Athlete, trial_time) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  purrr::map(function(x) {
    x %>%
      arrange(time) %>%
      group_by(Athlete, trial_time) %>%
      summarise(time_avg = mean(time[1:2], na.rm = TRUE))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  spread(trial_time, time_avg)
```

Comment: I don't think you want `desc(time)` b/c you want the average of the two fastest times.

Comment: So, I am arranging of the highest one to the lowest one and selecting the two firsts rows and calculate the mean.

Comment: Right but the fastest times are the the smallest times not the largest

Comment: Yeah, sorry, so you just need to remove the function `desc` and you have what you want. Sorry.

Comment: I think you're both really close!
emillman, is there away to alter your solution so that say trial is the slowest for the final time (0_20m), that it eliminates that entire trial from the mean calculation. Because an athlete might have a slower 0_10m time but make up for it and have a fast 0_20m time within the same trial. So the 0_20m time dictates whether the other splits are included in the mean, despite if the split times within that trial are faster than another trial. I'm not sure if that makes sense!

Comment: Andryas - I tried your solution taking out the desc(time) but had an error Column `trial_time` is unknown stemming from the function part of the code. Not sure why.

Comment: Try now, I add how I put the data and modified the arrange and summarise.

Comment: Yes you nailed it! It does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you! Would you be able to briefly explain how your function works? It helps me learn to hear how the veteran R users find their solutions.

Comment: You can run step by step to understand what was done, or I suggest to use this https://github.com/daranzolin/ViewPipeSteps.

Answer (score 0):

First to create the data.frame.

```
x <- read.table(text="x Athlete 0_10m_1 10_20m_1 0_20m_1 0_10m_2 10_20m_2 0_20m_2 0_10m_3 10_20m_3 0_20m_3
1 Athlete 1   2.005    1.320   3.325   1.904    1.306   3.210   1.993    1.316   3.309
2 Athlete 2   1.967    1.383   3.350   1.931    1.391   3.322   2.005    1.399   3.404
3 Athlete 3   2.008    1.381   3.389   2.074    1.365   3.439   2.047    1.408   3.455
4 Athlete 4   1.817    1.286   3.103   1.924    1.285   3.209      NA       NA      NA", header=T, check.names=F)


x %>% select(-x) %>% 
   gather("split", "time", -Athlete) %>% 
   mutate(split = gsub("_\\d$","", split)) %>% 
   group_by(Athlete, split) %>% 
   arrange(time) %>% 
   slice(1:2) %>% 
   summarize(Avg = mean(time))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Athlete [4]
#   Athlete split    Avg
#     <int> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1       1 0_10m   1.95
# 2       1 0_20m   3.26
# 3       1 10_20m  1.31
# 4       2 0_10m   1.95
# 5       2 0_20m   3.34
# 6       2 10_20m  1.39
# 7       3 0_10m   2.03
# 8       3 0_20m   3.41
# 9       3 10_20m  1.37
#10       4 0_10m   1.87
#11       4 0_20m   3.16
#12       4 10_20m  1.29
```